# How to use DataDog pipline processor to transform a JSON array

Tags: datadog

For the following payload that uploaded to DataDog logs

```
{
"test":["a", "b", "a"]
}
```

I would like to have a processor to transform that JSON to the following format

```
{
"test": {{"a": 2}, {"b": 1}}
}
```

What processor should I use and how to achieve such a transformation?

Is there a way I can write a Python script as a processor in a pipeline? That will be much easier comparing using mappers